# Can we use %rowtype attribute inside the plsql record?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Can we use %rowtype attribute inside the plsql record like the below code..

type xx is RECORD
(   v_emp   employees%rowtype ,
v_loc   departments.LOCATION_ID%type
);
v_data xx;

Comment: What does the compiler tell you when you try to execute this code?

Comment: Actually i was trying the below code:

Declare

type xx is RECORD ( v_emp employees%rowtype ,
                    v_loc departments.LOCATION_ID%type );
v_data xx;

Begin

Select e.*, 
        (select location_id 
         from departments d 
         where d.department_id = e.department_id) loc_id 
into v_data
from employees e 
where e.employee_id = 102;

End;

error msg: 
PLS-00597: expression 'V_DATA' in the INTO list is of wrong type

Comment: This is a very different question. Because result set is flat, while the record type is structured. You need to execute two `select` statements to fill the corresponding attributes. Or create a schema type and use a type constructor in the `select` statement. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9a0a07a92fd9d20e16b3aafd128f1901)

Answer (score 0):

I can, and I hope you can too.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    type xx is RECORD
  3      ( v_emp emp%rowtype ,
  4        v_loc dept.LOC%type );
  5    v_data xx;
  6  begin
  7    v_data.v_emp.ename := 'LF';
  8    v_data.v_loc := 'x';
  9
 10    dbms_output.put_line(v_data.v_emp.ename ||', '|| v_data.v_loc);
 11  end;
 12  /
LF, x

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```